# Learning the base for programming in C

Tags: programming

it's been a while since I think about starting to programming in C and after that to learn programming in C# and I search a lot on google but couldn't find a good guide to start learning base programming in C .However I found that Eclipe integrates very good with Ubuntu and it's a good programming environment for starting to program in C but somebody can give please some links with guides or tell me where can I find the bases for starting to program in C ,and I mean good base because I found a lot of incomplete guides over google ? And if I don't ask to much please give some tips of how to start and how to use Eclipse.Every help will be welcome ,thanks.

Comment: This isn't really Ubuntu specific. Just head into your local library and pick up a non-fiction book on C. While I don't think Stack Overflow will appreciate requests for tutorials, you are welcome to search around there, and ask for help with specific, concrete questions. Do be warned that I feel as if the site is unfriendly to newer users.

Comment: Try https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming and for reference the detailed https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html

Comment: But surely we can show how to configure Ubuntu to be able to compile C programs and how to write, compile and run a minimal C program in Ubuntu? I think it's a good question.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to complicate things with Eclipse and stuff if you want to learn C (which is also an interesting choice of a first programming language... while not discouraging you, I'm curious about your motives). I think it would be much more useful to learn how all the low-level bits (source code, compiler, headers, libraries, debugger, makefiles) fit together and then, if you want, to transition to an IDE.

From the [Learn C the Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych1.html#x6-100001.1) book linked by Goddard:

> An IDE, or "Integrated Development Environment" will turn you stupid.
>   They are the worst tools if you want to be a good programmer because
>   they hide what's going on from you, and your job is to know what's
>   going on. They are useful if you're trying to get something done and
>   the platform is designed around a particular IDE, but for learning to
>   code C (and many other languages) they are pointless.

You surely don't need Eclipse to write a "Hello, World" program in C. First install stuff needed to compile programs:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then open a text editor and type something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

save the file as `hello.c`. In terminal, run

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

you'll find an executable file called `hello` in the same directory. Run it:

```
./hello
```

It prints "Hello, World". Magic! Now get a book on C and try to modify the program to do something interesting.

Answer (score 2):

A good book to add to Sergey's answer is listed below.  This is the recommended route to go for a fresh developer.  The Ubuntu/Linux development world is bitter sweet.  A big learning curve in my opinion, but once you learn it the world is open and free for the most part.

This is a good resource
http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/

Comment: Thank you all very much ,the reason why I want to start programming is because I really like Gnu/Linux Open Source Sytems and I would like in future to contribute for Ubuntu development but to do that U have to know the basic programming  and I don't want to switch to windows for learning that, I want to do it in Ubuntu that's why I asked the question,Thanks again you all :D